# on error for try catch, the variable is returning an unexpected value

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating the Facebook API for user profile details... when working with a try catch to get the facebook response.

```
try {
      $request = new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/' . $user);
      $response = $request->execute();
      $results = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $fx) {
      //echo "requested " . $user . " - " . $fx->getCode();
      //echo $fx->getMessage();
      unset($results);
      $results = null;
    }
    print_r($results);

    return $results;
```

Here is the problem, when the $user does not exist on FACEBOOK, FB response from the graphobject return error code 803. 
In which case I am trying to catch that as the exception, and setting the $results as null.

However, $results in this case is never null or never gets set to null.

The expected behavior is:

> call FB API, if results is good, return array. if results is bad,
>   handle error and return null.

[edit]
controller:

$cover = $this->facebook->get_profile($brand_facebook);
    $picture = $this->facebook->get_picture($brand_facebook);

```
print_r($cover);

if(!is_null($cover)) {
  $brand->cover = $cover['cover']->source;
}
if(!is_null($picture))
  $brand->picture = $picture['url'];
}
```

get_profile($brand_facebook); should have errored and returned null, but it instead returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [<!DOCTYPE_html>
<html_lang] => "en" id="facebook">
  <head>
    <title>Facebook | Error</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <style>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
  unset($results); //<-- Not necesary
  $results = null;
```

You don't need those two lines... with $result = null is enough. However I would do this to achieve the expected behavior.

```
try {
  $request = new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/' . $user);
  $response = $request->execute();
  $results = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();




//Since you are not using a special handle for this type of error
//let's use just a generic exception and see if you get the expected
//behavior 
} catch(Exception $fx) { 



  //echo "requested " . $user . " - " . $fx->getCode();
  //echo $fx->getMessage();
  return null; //Returns null on error
}


return $results;
```

Comment: weird, even when returning null, the method itself is returning a response. please see edits above.

Comment: I'll try this but I believe I may have found the cause. When the request ($user) is a string with invalid char such as space it generates a Facebook error. For whatever reason FacebookResponseException does not catch it... If ($user) is valid (without special char or spaces) the exception is then caught.

Comment: What i did was use regex to strip spaces and non alphanumeric char from $user and this was working fine. It's odd that Facebook doesn't have an exception for invalid char.

Comment: confirmed. even with your edited solution, the error returned from facebook when using spaces or special characters for $user in the code above return a facebook error page and not an exception. Thus causing the try catch to not catch it... it treats it as a successful call.

Comment: I understand, then the problem is not about error catching because there is no error to catch haha